# spring security csrf protection for ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, cookies, spring-security

I am using spring security for my application. Doing form based auth w/ csrf token embedded in the form. After user is authenticated, the session cookie allows pages to accessed. 
I need to protect against csrf for the ajax calls in my app.

Spring provides a way that a token can be sent from server to client

```
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

This token needs to be sent back to make ajax calls.

```
var client = rest.chain(csrf, {
token: $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"),
name: $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content")
});
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax

Ques.: A possible attacker (HTML code in another browser tab) can still request the whole page from my app (this will work as session cookie will be sent along w/ the request automatically by the browser). The response from the server will contain the csrf token. Now attacker could use this token to make ajax calls. Doesn't this create a security vulnerability?

Please suggest if I am missing something to protect against this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

No, a page in another tab cannot just request the whole page from your app. As the Wikipedia [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) page says:

> "Cross-domain" AJAX requests are forbidden by default because of their
>   ability to perform advanced requests (POST, PUT, DELETE and other
>   types of HTTP requests, along with specifying custom HTTP headers)
>   that introduce many cross-site scripting security issues.

If your app explicitly sends CORS headers, extra care must be taken. Otherwise you should be safe regarding this matter.